# Inject provisioning profile name with xcodebuild command

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, xcodebuild

We are using a manual signing strategy for our iOS app. Our CI/CD pipeline is set up on Jenkins and we need to build the app using the xcodebuild command. We are using the following command to archive the app.

```
xcodebuild -scheme Integration -xcconfig Integration.xcconfig -configuration Debug clean archive -archivePath build/app -destination generic/platform=iOS
```

When we archive the app using the above command, it always fails on the below error. I would like to know how to pass the provisioning profile name with the above xcodebuild command.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution. It can be done by using:

```
xcodebuild -scheme Integration -xcconfig Integration.xcconfig -configuration Debug clean archive -archivePath build/app -destination generic/platform=iOS PROVISIONING_PROFILE="[Your profile Unique ID here]"
```